# After adding my site to Google Search Console multiple ways (no www, www, https) which should I use?

Tags: google-search-console, https, xml-sitemap, no-www

I've submitted

- example.com URL with no-www
- www.example.com with www
- https www.example.com with https://

to Google Webmaster Tools as suggested by [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83685/should-i-submit-https-and-https-www-in-webmaster-tools).

Should I submit the sitemap in the https version or the non-www or www version?

Answer (score 1):

Whichever is the canonical version.

If you haven't already done so, you should set up permanent redirects from the variants to your canonical domain. For example, if you decide the `https` version with `www` is canonical, you'd set up redirects as follows:

- `http://www.example.com` -- 301 --> `https://www.example.com`
- `https://example.com` -- 301 --> `https://www.example.com`

And so on.

In Search Console, you can [combine variants of the same site as a set](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/05/tie-your-sites-together-with-property.html). This will give you combined analytic data.

Comment: Okay but should i monitor the data of non-www, www or https version in Search Console?

Comment: Again, whichever is the canonical