# If redirects for variations are in place, can I safely consolidate down to one Google Search Console property?

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, https, no-www

I am redirecting using .htaccess to always use www, always use HTTPS.  At this point, can I remove the duplicate Google Search Console properties (non-www and http)?

Comment: See also: [Moving from HTTP to HTTPS in Google Search Console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68435/moving-from-http-to-https-in-google-search-console)

Comment: Related: [Should I submit https:// and https://www in webmaster tools?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83685/should-i-submit-https-and-https-www-in-webmaster-tools)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Google even prefers it. Only submit the URL you prefer your site to be accessed with.
If https://www.domain.tld - Submit only that one.

After receiving a notice from Google (2-3 years ago?), I had to reorganize all my domains with Google when I switched some domains to https and whether or not they used  www.

In short, it has to do with directly connecting to your site without redirects.