# Google Search Console - which domain properties in case of different language folders

Tags: google-search-console, local-seo, internationalization

I have a website available in 5 languages.

- domain.com in english
- domain.com/fr in french
- domain.com/it in italian
- and so on and so forth...

In GSC, should I add one **domain property** with domain.com to track all the data for all the languages with all the sitemaps for each language listed under the domain property?

Or should I have 1 property for each language, each with its own sitemaps?

I found information regarding subdomains like support.domain.com or m.domain.com but nothing regarding language folders. 
Is there a "best-practice"? Is there a difference? Solution 1 seems easier and less tedious... but could I be penalized in any way?

Apparently the "domain property" option is pretty new. I've read [this post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83685/should-i-submit-https-and-http-in-google-search-console-both-with-and-with) but it doesn't mention language folders for international websites. 
I've also searched SE but did not find any similar question. 
Finally, [google support's page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en) doesn't talk about internationalized websites.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!

Comment: A property is one site, not a portion of a site. You cannot make a property example.com/folder. If you want to track languages, then you should consider using a sub-domain such as fr.example.com. This could be a property.

Comment: @closetnoc ok thanks for the reply, post it as an answer so I can accept it ;)